# Jquery Highlight on preloaded input value

Tags: jquery, input, highlight

I have a highlight jquery script which highlights a words in text which you enter in two input above.... Now I wanna set up second input with preloaded value in html tag (value="something") which highlight's text immediatly after document is loaded....

My current situation is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/bZYqK/

### html:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" class="span1 disabled" id="field1" name="field1">
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="span1 disabled" id="field2" name="field2" value="rhoncus quis porta">
    <br>
    <p>
        Vestibulum rhoncus urna sed urna euismod, ut cursus erüos molestie. 
        Nulla sed ante ut diam gravida auctor eu quis augue. Donec egäet diam 
        malesuada, consectetur orci at, ultrices tellus. Duis id dui vel sem 
        consequat rutrum eget non orci. Nullam sit amet libero odiö. 
        Vestibulum sapien sapien, molestie quis porta nec, sodales nec felis. 
        Mauris vehicula, erat eu consectetur viverra, dui tellus laoreet 
        dolor, quis faucibus turpis eros non mi.
    </p>
</body>
```

### script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#field1').bind('keyup change', function (ev) {
        // pull in the new value
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();

        // remove any old highlighted terms
        $('body').removeHighlight('span.highlight1');

        // disable highlighting if empty
        if (searchTerm) {
            var terms = searchTerm.split(/(\s)/);
            $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
                // highlight the new term
                term = term.trim();
                if (term != "") $('body').highlight(term, 'highlight1');
            });
        }
    });

    $('#field2').bind('keyup change', function (ev) {
        // pull in the new value
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();

        // remove any old highlighted terms
        $('body').removeHighlight(['span.highlight2']);

        // disable highlighting if empty
        if (searchTerm) {
            var terms = searchTerm.split(/\W+/);
            $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
                // highlight the new term
                term = term.trim();
                if (term != "") $('body').highlight(term, 'highlight2');
            });
        }
    });
});


jQuery.fn.highlight = function (pat, className) {
    function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
        var skip = 0;
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
            if (pos >= 0) {
                var spannode = document.createElement('span');
                spannode.className = className || 'highlight';
                var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
                var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
                var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
                skip = 1;
            }
        } else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) { i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat); }
        }
        return skip;
    }
    return this.each(function () {
        innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
    });
};

jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function (classNames) {
    function newNormalize(node) {
        for (var i = 0, children = node.childNodes, nodeCount = children.length; i <  nodeCount; i++) {
            var child = children[i];
            if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                newNormalize(child);
                continue;
            }
            if (child.nodeType != 3) { continue; }
            var next = child.nextSibling;
            if (next == null || next.nodeType != 3) { continue; }
            var combined_text = child.nodeValue + next.nodeValue;
            new_node = node.ownerDocument.createTextNode(combined_text);
            node.insertBefore(new_node, child);
            node.removeChild(child);
            node.removeChild(next);
            i--;
            nodeCount--;
        }
    }
    var selectors = classNames;
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(classNames) === '[object Array]') selectors = classNames.join(',');

    return this.find(selectors).each(function () {
        var thisParent = this.parentNode;
        thisParent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
        newNormalize(thisParent);
    }).end();
};
```

### css:

```
.highlight2, .highlight1 {
    background-color: #fff34d;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    /* FF1+ */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    /* Saf3-4 */
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* FF3.5+ */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* Opera 10.5+, IE 9.0 */
}
.highlight2, .highlight1 {
    padding:1px 4px;
    margin:0 -4px;
}
.highlight2 {
    background-color: #cecece;
}
```

Is it possible soultion to set up those inputs on window load, document ready, or something with keys? I'm not sure.... please help me

you can update my jsfiddle

Comment: found small error, updated answer. i think you'll find it more useful than such separated and elongated calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .triggerHandler() jquery's method:

{ in case of your jsfiddle, you have to set methods before calling it, or use wrap in HEAD }

http://jsfiddle.net/bZYqK/2/

```
.triggerHandler('change')
```

Comment: love the simplest solution :)

Comment: @dzordz if that's the case, you could make it shorter and replace `triggerHandler('change')` with just simply `change()`

Comment: @SpYk3HH yes and no, because using alias change() which internally means trigger('change') will bubbles through DOM which in some case could give not expected result. For consistency, it's better to trigger only the specific handler, not the event

Comment: @roasted lol, or he could just hit "change". there won't be any "unexpected" event. If there was, I'd have all kinds of problems on my hands! :P

Comment: @SpYk3HH i don't understand what you mean, i'm talking about consistency between trigger an event which bubbles between just calling the handler. For change event, as its refers to input and as input haven't got any other nested inputs, yes, calling simply .change() would give expected result. But now, what about a click event? So, like i said, for consistency better is to use triggerHandler()

Comment: @roasted you're still new in this carrer, huh? you consistency kids gimmie the laugh i needed for this Monday. Good stuff tho. stay organized!

Comment: @roasted by all means please do! Aye Oh! Let's Go! Aye Oh! SO! :P (because even coders can have a since of humor!)

Answer (score 1):

You're using a late enough version of jQuery, I'd switch to .on, move the repetitive function into it's own method, assign by delegation, and then simply trigger the state "change". Oh and add a common class name between your inputs to select.

What I mean is something like:

```
/* Be sure to include plugin BEFORE this script */
//  function to highlight words based on input
function setHighlight(e) {
    // pull in the new value
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    // remove any old highlighted terms
    $('body').removeHighlight('span.highlight1');
    // disable highlighting if empty
    if (searchTerm) {
        var terms = searchTerm.split(/(\s)/);
        $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
            // highlight the new term
            term = term.trim();
            if (term != "") {
                //  this will check the id of your inputs for proper highlight class to add to body
                switch ($this.prop("id")) {
                    case "field1":
                        $('body').highlight(term, 'highlight1');
                        break;
                    case "field2":
                        $('body').highlight(term, 'highlight2');
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    // delegate method to keyup and change for all elements having the class ".inp-highlight"
    //      "inp-highlight" is the class name I used in my example (see jsFiddle link)
    $(document).on("keyup change", ".inp-highlight", setHighlight);
    //  with the method asigned and text already in the value of the box, I need only call for change method
    $("#field2").change();
    //  Thanks to jQuery "chaining", you could also insert the text and call change as:
    //  $("#field2").text("Text to search for on load!").change();
});
```

## jsFiddle

---

### Full Code w Plugin w/o Comments

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function (pat, className) {
    function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
        var skip = 0;
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
            if (pos >= 0) {
                var spannode = document.createElement('span');
                spannode.className = className || 'highlight';
                var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
                var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
                var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
                skip = 1;
            }
        }
        else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) { i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat); }
        }
        return skip;
    }
    return this.each(function () {
        innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
    });
};

jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function (classNames) {
    function newNormalize(node) {
        for (var i = 0, children = node.childNodes, nodeCount = children.length; i <  nodeCount; i++) {
            var child = children[i];
            if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                newNormalize(child);
                continue;
            }
            if (child.nodeType != 3) { continue; }
            var next = child.nextSibling;
            if (next == null || next.nodeType != 3) { continue; }
            var combined_text = child.nodeValue + next.nodeValue;
            new_node = node.ownerDocument.createTextNode(combined_text);
            node.insertBefore(new_node, child);
            node.removeChild(child);
            node.removeChild(next);
            i--;
            nodeCount--;
        }
    }
    var selectors = classNames;
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(classNames) === '[object Array]') selectors = classNames.join(',');

    return this.find(selectors).each(function () {
        var thisParent = this.parentNode;
        thisParent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
        newNormalize(thisParent);
    }).end();
};

function setHighlight(e) {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    $('body').removeHighlight('span.highlight1');
    if (searchTerm) {
        var terms = searchTerm.split(/(\s)/);
        $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
            // highlight the new term
            term = term.trim();
            if (term != "") {
                switch ($this.prop("id")) {
                    case "field1":
                        $('body').highlight(term, 'highlight1');
                        break;
                    case "field2":
                        $('body').highlight(term, 'highlight2');
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(document).on("keyup change", ".inp-highlight", setHighlight);
    $("#field2").change();
});
```

---

### Updated from comments

*Splitting*

There are a couple ways to remove splitting on space. Option one is as simple as changing the "setHighlight" function to the following:

```
function setHighlight(e) {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().trim();
    $('body').removeHighlight('span.highlight1');

    if (searchTerm) {
        switch ($this.prop("id")) {
            case "field1":
                $('body').highlight(searchTerm, 'highlight1');
                break;
            case "field2":
                $('body').highlight(searchTerm, 'highlight2');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This will simply no longer check to split spaces. instead it will always search whatever text is given. See example and note I changed preloaded value to something it could find on load.

## Example

The second option might be to change the function all together. This would also mean changing the way the method is "assigned", thus you would need to pass the input in, or its value as a parameter. This could then allow for an "option" of splitting on a given character (like space); The change would be like:

```
//  change the following line in the load function
//  $(document).on("keyup change", ".inp-highlight", setHighlight);
//  to
$(document).on("keyup change", ".inp-highlight", function(e) { setHighlight($(this)); });
//  given the new method function, if you wanted to split by space, 
//  the call would be
//  setHighlight($(this), " ");
```

then change the setHighlight method to be:

```
function setHighlight($this, splitChar) {
    var searchTerm = $this.val().trim(),
        highlight = function(id, value) {
            switch (id) {
                case "field1":
                    $('body').highlight(value, 'highlight1');
                    break;
                case "field2":
                    $('body').highlight(value, 'highlight2');
                    break;
            }
        };
    $('body').removeHighlight('span.highlight1');
    if (searchTerm != "") {
        if (splitChar) {
            var terms = searchTerm.split(/(\s)/);
            $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
                term = term.trim();
                if (term != "") highlight($this.prop("id"), term);
            });
        }
        else {
            highlight($this.prop("id"), searchTerm);
        }
    }
}
```

## Example

Comment: @dzordz I thought you mights, tried to take what you had and bundle it up nice and snug.

Comment: do you maybe know how can i turn off separation of search terms with space?

Comment: @dzordz I don't quite understand what you mean, but i'm sure we can figure it out :D

Comment: `var terms = searchTerm.split(/(\s)/);` this splits input highlights on space... when you enter a word it gets highlighted and then you press space and you can highlight another word which is not next till that first word.... I wanna to turn this off so I could highlight something like "Vestibulum rhoncus" (in my example) together

Comment: oic, gimmie a minute to look at it

Comment: @dzordz I updated my answer to include what you asked about! See in answer, below where it says **Updated from comments**

Comment: ahh great! But I'm newbie at jquery, truly said... I hoped that you would update my example from start, precisely before your edit of entire code... It's not because of me..

Comment: @dzordz I'm assuming you want the code from first splitting example. Everything is in the jsfiddle. Just copy and past the JS http://jsfiddle.net/bZYqK/10/

Comment: yea but, my problem is that you add a new class, I was hoping that it could be applied only on one of inputs/classes that is already there... and that's a example with your changed version of code... I know that example from question is nooby... But I wanted that 'nospace' option be aplied to that example from question

Comment: I've managed to do it with your example in the end... thanks :)... could you look at one of my other questions? I'm really stuck on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028105/jquery-autoscroll-offset-from-top

Answer (score 1):

I would move all your highlight functionality into it's own function:

```
function highlightText(searchTerm, removeHighlight, highlight){
        // remove any old highlighted terms
        $('body').removeHighlight(removeHighlight);

        // disable highlighting if empty
        if (searchTerm) {
            var terms = searchTerm.split(/(\s)/);
            $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
                // highlight the new term
                term = term.trim();
                if (term != "") $('body').highlight(term, highlight);
            });

        }
}
```

then you can use the following to fire the highlight and bind your original two events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#field1').bind('keyup change', function (ev) {
        highlightText($(this).val(), 'span.highlight1', 'highlight1');
    });

    var field2 = $('#field2');

    field2.bind('keyup change', function (ev) {
        highlightText($(this).val(), 'span.highlight2', 'highlight2');
    });

    highlightText(field2.val(), 'span.highlight2', 'highlight2');
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/NfAKd/)