# jquery autoscroll offset from top

Tags: jquery, offset, autoscroll

I wanna set "autoscroll to class" jquery script in that way so it shows targeted class couple of pixels in offset from top of the window. Is something like that possible with this plugin?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/cybMJ/

html:

```
<div id="nav-dock"> 
<a id="prev" href="#">&uarr; Prev</a> 
    <a id="next" href="#">&darr; Next</a>
 </div>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <div class=text>
<b>First</b>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  In iaculis augue sapien, in facilisis lorem ullamcorper eu. 
 Nunc at nulla metus. Pellentesque posuere quam id 
 nunc <span class="highlight1">posuere</span> sagittis. Vivamus varius 
 euismod nisi, ac condimentum mauris aliquam vitae. Ut faucibus eros vitae 
 pharetra eleifend. Pellentesque volutpat facilisis porttitor. Nullam in 
 turpis a nulla placerat placerat.    
 </div>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <div class=text>
<b>Second</b>
Cras semper purus sit amet euismod molestie. Vivamus dapibus hendrerit elit 
 eget tristique. Ut pulvinar adipiscing magna, eget viverra risus sollicitudin et.
  Morbi odio lacus, malesuada vel dapibus vitae, blandit ut metus.
 Vivamus cursus fringilla <span class="highlight1">felis</span> id facilisis.   
 </div>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <div class=text>
<b>Third</b>
Aliquam et mattis mi. Mauris vel sagittis orci, id tempor neque. 
 Aenean at arcu eu quam suscipit fermentum. Sed tempor, urna in malesuada 
 sollicitudin, nulla erat <span class="highlight1">malesuada</span> ligula, 
 sed  ultricies ipsum dui a dui. Ut at sem quis lectus aliquet vulputate.     
 </div>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <div class=text>
<b>Fifth</b>
Praesent sagittis tortor a purus euismod ultrices eu vitae est. 
 Vivamus a facilisis dolor. Donec id tincidunt erat. Fusce elementum imperdiet 
 augue, at pretium lectus <span class="highlight1">dictum</span> sit amet. 
 Nullam pharetra dui arcu, ut tempus nulla interdum non. Etiam et mattis augue.    
 </div>
```

script:

```
$(function() {

function scroll(direction) {

    var scroll, i,
            positions = [],
            here = $(window).scrollTop(),
            collection = $('.highlight1');

    collection.each(function() {
        positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'],10));
    });

    for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) { scroll = collection.get(i); break; }
        if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) { scroll = collection.get(i-1); break; }
    }

    if (scroll) {
        $.scrollTo(scroll, {
            duration: 750       
        });
    }

    return false;
}

$("#next,#prev").click(function() {        
    return scroll($(this).attr('id'));        
}).triggerHandler('click');

$(function() {

function scroll(direction) {

    var scroll, i,
            positions = [],
            here = $(window).scrollTop(),
            collection = $('.highlight1');

    collection.each(function() {
        positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'],10));
    });

    for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) { scroll = collection.get(i); break; }
        if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) { scroll = collection.get(i-1); break; }
    }

    if (scroll) {
        $.scrollTo(scroll, {
            duration: 750       
        });
    }

    return false;
}

$("#next,#prev").click(function() {        
    return scroll($(this).attr('id'));        
}).triggerHandler('click');

});
```

You can update my jsfiddle freely.

Comment: please help I'm desperate :(

Comment: just got back from lunch, gimie a few and i'll look at this, gota handle something else first

Comment: Ok, no problem... when you can :)

Comment: looking at it now, so do you mean you want it to scroll to a few pix "above" the element?

Comment: Yes, you could say that way, so that element doesn't apper on egde/top of window but, for example 50 pixels away from the edge/top..

Comment: ok, and you absolutely want to go to the elements having class "highlight1"? or would you rather it scroll to parent? or is that why you wan't the 50px? because if you're wanting parent (the whole paragraph) i can show you how to do that way easy

Comment: I would rather go to the element having that class "highlight1" if it's possible somehow...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31542/discussion-between-spyk3hh-and-dzordz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I rewrote thing for you and broke them down with full explination of all the moving parts. Although, with comments gone, you'll find this code much shorter than your own!

## Example <sub>with comments</sub>

```
//  the following establishes your own namespace, place everything about the scroll function in this namespace
var hlScroll = {
    //  properties
    buffer: 50, //  pixel buffer, positive is px above element, negative would move it so many pix below
    speed: 500, //  scroll speed, 1000 = 1second
    //  method
    scrollTo: function(e) {
        var gotoEle;    //  will be the element to find "top" too
        switch ($(this).attr('id')) {   //  same as an if else, but more visually sound on 2 strings in question
            case "next":    //  obviously go to next element
                //  filter is jquery function that allows us to get only certain elements in a collection
                //  here, our collection is ALL elements having class "highlight1"
                //  the filter method is kind of like .each, it goes through each element, the i means "index"
                //  in order for an element to stay in the collection, it must return true
                //  in this case, looking for "next", I see if current element's top is higher than window top + our buffer
                //  by including the buffer, I can make suer not to skip an element that might be "close" to the buffer but not over
                gotoEle = $('.highlight1').filter(function(i) { return $(this).offset().top > ($(window).scrollTop() + hlScroll.buffer) }).first();
                //  since we are getting next, we only want the first element returned, thus `.first()` will return just that!
                break;
            case "prev":
                //  a lil dif from above, here we look for the last element who's top is higher than the window
                gotoEle = $('.highlight1').filter(function(i) { return $(this).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() }).last();
                break;
        }
        //  the if statement here keeps the scroll from firing if no element found
        //  if the element is found, we animate the page to scroll the element previously selected, - the buffer, keeping it so many pixels above the element (unless the buffer is negative)
        if (gotoEle.length) $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: gotoEle.offset().top - hlScroll.buffer  }, hlScroll.speed);
        //  notice i selected "html, body". these are our main page elements which hold the page scroll
        //  you could adjust this in the future to scroll a parent container instead!
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#next, #prev").on("click", hlScroll.scrollTo).click();
});
```

## Example <sub>without comments</sub>

```
var hlScroll = {
    buffer: 50,
    speed: 500,
    scrollTo: function(e) {
        var gotoEle;
        switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
            case "next":
                gotoEle = $('.highlight1').filter(function(i) { return $(this).offset().top > ($(window).scrollTop() + hlScroll.buffer) }).first();
                break;
            case "prev":
                gotoEle = $('.highlight1').filter(function(i) { return $(this).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() }).last();
                break;
        }
        if (gotoEle.length) $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: gotoEle.offset().top - hlScroll.buffer  }, hlScroll.speed);
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#next, #prev").on("click", hlScroll.scrollTo).click();
});
```

Further reading:

- [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
- [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
- [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)
- [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) [formally known as .[bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), .[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), & .[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in versions pre-1.7]
- [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Comment: in the fiddle everything is ok

but on my project:

it seems that I have problem with that void in link...
it goes till the first element,
but on next it doesn't go to next element...

and with # in links screen flashes...

Comment: `href="javascript:void(0)"` is basically the same as saying `.click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`. The only thing it does is cancel the browser from going anywhere, as it shouldn't be, the `#` flash is from the browser reloading on your url plus `#`. as for it not going, it should not be having a problem. there must be another issue. May I see a link? is your site reachable online?

Comment: to trouble shoot it, just before the line `if (gotoEle.length) ` place something like `console.log(gotoEle)` and then check console on clicks to see what, if any, element it's getting

Comment: could I contact you on your mail?